# Query goes wrong when checking if the user exists in other table

Tags: mysql, join

I have a query that shows a list of **revisions** and **employees** for every revision..

### Now I'm trying to show if the given employee already has a row in the answers table..

This is the overview of the database

[image]

This is my working query that shows the list of revisions and employees

```
SELECT l.id, l.naam, r.id as revision_id, r.beschrijving, e.id as employee_id, e.voornaam, e.achternaam,
FROM lists l
INNER JOIN revisions r ON l.id = r.list_id
INNER JOIN employeelists el ON el.list_id= l.id
INNER JOIN employees e ON e.id = el.employee_id
INNER JOIN customers c ON c.id = e.customer_id
WHERE customer_id = :id AND r.actief = 1
```

[image]

Now I've tried several things to see if the employee already has a record in the answers table.. But It's failing the whole time..

### Try 1 : Adding the Answers table with a left outer join

```
SELECT l.id, l.naam, r.id as revision_id, r.beschrijving, e.id as employee_id, e.voornaam, e.achternaam,
**CASE WHEN a.coach_id != 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as FILLED IN**
FROM lists l"""
INNER JOIN revisions r ON l.id = r.list_id
**LEFT OUTER JOIN answers a ON a.revision_id = r.id**
INNER JOIN employeelists el ON el.list_id= l.id
INNER JOIN employees e ON e.id = el.employee_id
INNER JOIN customers c ON c.id = e.customer_id
WHERE customer_id = :id AND r.actief = 1
```

**now the problem is that every employee is shown multiple times...**
[image]

#### This is the SQLFiddle of the working database, The only thing i can't do is check if the given employee ( werknemer ) exists in the answers ( antwoorden ) table..

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0c01c/4

#### Any idea on how i can solve this? I tried a subquery, but that didn't work out either.. Thanks!

### Problem with Query Now

I thought i was correct but there's one more error. in the **answers** table, it shows results for **werknemer_id ( employee_id ) = 78**. For the **revisie ( revision ) 1 and 2**

While there is only results for revisie 1 (screenshot below)

[image]

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs and/or an sqlfiddle TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED result set.

Comment: Hi Strawberry! thanks! i added the Sqlfiddle

Comment: Isn't it as simple as this...? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0c01c/13

Answer (score 0):

How about this exist column will have 0 if not in `antwoorden` and 1 if exist

```
    SELECT l.id, l.naam, r.revisie as revisie, r.id as revisie_id, r.beschrijving, w.id as werknemer, w.voornaam, w.achternaam
    , a.werknemer_id,
(CASE WHEN a.werknemer_id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ) AS `exist`
    FROM lijsten l
    INNER JOIN revisies r ON l.id = r.lijst_id
    INNER JOIN werknemerlijsten wl ON wl.lijst_id = l.id
    INNER JOIN werknemers w ON w.id = wl.werknemer_id
    INNER JOIN klanten k ON k.id = w.klant_id
    LEFT JOIN   antwoorden a ON w.id = a.werknemer_id
    WHERE klant_id = 39 AND r.actief = 1
    GROUP BY  r.beschrijving, w.id
```

### [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0c01c/17)

Comment: I think this might be it! What i don't understand is the GROUP BY. I read about it .. but how do you determine on what you have to group? Thanks!

Comment: Just check the repeated results in your query and i have noticed unique combination of `r.beschrijving, w.id` from your previous query so i applied `GROUP BY  r.beschrijving, w.id`

Comment: Hmh. I added screenshots of the problem now, Damnit we're so close! and thankyou

Comment: @MiguelStevens see this fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0c01c/37 you are showing `r.id AS revisie_id` which has a join with  lijsten `INNER JOIN revisies r ON l.id = r.lijst_id`,instead if you see `a.revisie_id AS antwoodenrevise` it shows the revise 1 for werknemer_id 78 .Hope it makes sense your query is fine but you are showing wrong column

Comment: Fixed it i think! ( with help of someone ) .. Using a Double Argument for the LEFT JOIN.. is this good practice?  Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4bfc94/1

Comment: @MiguelStevens Yes you can join table on multiple conditions there is no problem but note thing this will only join the data set where these conditions fulfill

Comment: Thanks! this is the desired result, only see the "ingevuld" as 1 when the desider coach ( 1 in this case ) is in the answers table http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/41b08/9

Answer (score 0):

### Final solution

This is the final outcome, only see 'ingevuld' is 1 if the desired coach (1 in thise case) is in the answers table.

```
SELECT l.id, l.naam, r.revisie AS revisie, r.id AS revisie_id, r.beschrijving, w.id AS werknemer, w.voornaam, w.achternaam, a.coach_id,
CASE WHEN a.coach_id = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS ingevuld
FROM lijsten l
INNER JOIN revisies r ON l.id = r.lijst_id
INNER JOIN werknemerlijsten wl ON wl.lijst_id = l.id
INNER JOIN werknemers w ON w.id = wl.werknemer_id
INNER JOIN klanten k ON k.id = w.klant_id
LEFT JOIN antwoorden a ON w.id = a.werknemer_id AND r.id=a.revisie_id
WHERE klant_id = 39 AND r.actief = 1
group by r.id, w.id, a.coach_id
```